# AdView Banner (SubView) covers the bottom toolbar in my app. How do I make sure the toolbar is fixed below the banner?

Tags: ios

The code I am using to fix the adbanner to the bottom of the screen on any resolution is:

```
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-adView.frame.size.width, 
                        [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-adView.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, 
                        adView.frame.size.width, 
                        adView.frame.size.height)];
```

I just need some help in ensuring that my toolbar doesnt get covered. How do I do this?