# AdMob Banner Covers Bottom Toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, layout, admob

I have just loaded an AdMob test banner to my ViewController. I dragged in a View at storyboard level and set it to be the AdMob banner (and I fixed it's size to : 320x50).

But it covers my bottom toolbar.

In Xcode, I have set my toolbar (using storyboard constraints) to the bottom of the view (0 distance to bottom of view); and I set the AdMob banner view to sit just above the bottom toolbar (0 distance to bottom toolbar, using constraints in the storyboard).

When I run the simulator on my device, the banner appears at the bottom of the view on top of and covering my bottom toolbar.

How can I set my parameters so that the banner (if it displays) will always show just on top of the bottom toolbar, not cover it?

I found a the exact same question here :

[AdView Banner (SubView) covers the bottom toolbar in my app. How do I make sure the toolbar is fixed below the banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728270/adview-banner-subview-covers-the-bottom-toolbar-in-my-app-how-do-i-make-sure)

but the answer (which was not accepted) was :

> I had this same problem, simple fix for me. You probably have
>   "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" in your -viewDidLoad method. Move it
>   to your -viewDidAppear method instead and see if that fixes it.

I don't have a viewDidAppear method currently in my ViewController.swift file.

I also realise that the actual AdMob banner displayed on my iPhone 6 is full width - while I set a fixed size to the view in my storyboard that 'holds' the AdMob banner. So obviously, the constraints I set for the banner at storyboard level is being overridden here.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily try adding the `viewDidAppear` method to your `ViewController.swift` file (Xcode will even auto-complete the method for you). Then try adding the line from the other answer and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice from the related question:

[AdView Banner (SubView) covers the bottom toolbar in my app. How do I make sure the toolbar is fixed below the banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728270/adview-banner-subview-covers-the-bottom-toolbar-in-my-app-how-do-i-make-sure)

> I had this same problem, simple fix for me. You probably have
>   "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" in your -viewDidLoad method. Move it
>   to your -viewDidAppear method instead and see if that fixes it.

It worked for me also - in my own context.